# ios leak on ipad but fine in simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, libxml2

I am new to iOS development.
I am developing an iPad App.
I am using libxml2.
I am parsing HTML using the TouchXML arc port.

When running the app in simulator and testing it with Instruments, everything seems to work fine.
When running the app on the iPad on the other hand, I keep running into memory leaks.

It's the same code.

What could be causing this?

Comment: How did you determine you are running into leakages? By running Instruments?

Comment: Yes, I that's the way I tested it for leakage

Comment: What are you doing in the code with the unexpected leaks?

Comment: I am parsing html. The html can be dirty (including tags that aren't closed - img e.g.) I am using the parsed html to load data and show it

Comment: Unfortunately device and simulator are so different that you should not trust the simulator for things such as leaks. Only trust the device.

Comment: is that something in the libxml2 library ?